# how to serve appspot.com apps on custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application http://faqs4j.appspot.com. I have purchased a domain called **jobs4j**.
 I added domain using **application settings** in app engine console and also made necessory 
 CNAME changes in godaddy DNS managing console.

Now when I type in browser **in.jobs4j.com** it simply ridirects to **http://faqs4j.appspot.com**.But
 I want my application to be served under sub-domain in.jobs4j.com and not just redirection to 
 appspot domain. what configuration I am missing?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In the application dashboard, under **administration** / **application settings**, you have a section titled "**Domain setup**". In it you can configure domains to be used for this application.

The process will require you to set up a "google apps" account (don't worry, a single-user domain is free), then transfer the domain(s) you want to be managed by Google apps by setting up a CNAME entry in your domain zone file. The instructions show you how to do it. Of course, where the instructions recommend you define your CNAME subdomain as "www", you will want your subdomain to be called "in".

Comment: I have already performed these steps.But still it just redirects to my appspot.com domain.

Comment: Actually it works just fine: requesting '/' on your domain serves correctly from your appengine app. Your problem is, '/' on your domain is configured to return a file redirecting to the non-relative url `http://faqs4j.appspot.com/javafaq.action`.

Comment: exactly.. thanks for pointing it out . I just make some workaround in my welcome file to redirect it to http://jobs4j.com . many thanks again.

Comment: You can simply use relative URL in the redirect ("/javafaq.action") - this will redirect to the required path regardless of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google has ended the option to have a free Google Apps account, sigh!

However, we could still point the GAE app from a custom domain (non-Google apps owned).

> Step 1 : Go to **Application Settings** in the GAE dashboard and add a
>   custom domain. You will be asked to verify the domain during which
>   Google would basically create a TXT record in your DNS zone file.
>
> Step 2 : Once the 3rd party domain is verified, add the custom domain
>   for the app (my-gae-app.mydomain.app). It shows instructions
>   on how to add the CNAME entry for the domain.

Hope this helps!